# ServiceBusTrigger delayed in executions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

- Consumption Plan
- East US
- Runtime Version 3.0.14492.0
- 15 timer based functions; 3 ServiceBusTriggers
- Utilizing FunctionsStartup class to provide .NET Core DI to all functions
- AzureDevOps deploys function zip package via "Azure Functions" release task
- Nuget packages:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

My primary ServiceBusTrigger function is not firing when messages are available in the queue. This function has been running in production for 5 months. Starting last weekend, we saw the number of queue messages climbing and the number of function executions dropping. To be clear, the function works as expected, then simply stops executing.

In my `Startup.cs`, I'm configuring the auto-completion of messages.

```
builder.Services.Configure(delegate(ServiceBusOptions options)
{
    options.MessageHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = false;
});
```

The function uses a `ServiceBusTrigger`.
[image: function signature]

App Insights function activity shows normal processing, then complete silence. The large blocks to the right are where the function fires for the bulk of messages at once.
[image: app insights log]

The volume of messages within this specific queue correlates to the app insights log. Processing as normal, then the number of notifications slowly grows until they are all processed at once.

[image: queue depth]

- The first large batch simply processed on it's own. I didn't intervene at all.
- The second large batch processed after re-deploying functions

Comment: Check: 
1. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2456#issuecomment-369502028  
2. https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/210  
3. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/71#issuecomment-596805415

Comment: @krishg thanks for the links. No host.json comments. Based on the current deployment methods, trigger sync'ing isn't an issue (and I haven't seen it prior when adding new functions with the same deployment methods)

Comment: @TimGabrhel i guess this should be the problem of  cold start . Just in case if you have provided sevicebus connection string in connection string section of  your function app change it to appsettings section then you will not see this issue. The problem with consumption plan is that as long there is proper load on the queue its executes properly when the load reduces the execution also reduces .

Comment: @TimGabrhel, What about the 3rd one. "Make sure the service bus connection string access policy has the MANAGE access turned on for it. This will allow Azure Functions to be able to view the queue and topic metrics."

Comment: @kannangokul It's using app settings, no connection string settings. my issue here is the same deployed code went dark. It was working and working, then silence...then it picked up again on it's own.

Comment: @krishg yep, manage is checked. remember, this is a long time working func, not a new setup. access keys haven't changed either

Comment: I think it would need a deeper look from support. Please create an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues) sharing [the app name privately](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately).

Comment: @krishg Done - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6786 thank you